# Azure Policy Compliance "NotFound"

Tags: azure, security, policy

Applied the Azure Security Benchmark to a Management Group. Now, tuning it to get rid of the false positives and unnecessary items. Running into a few issues that are similar to this:

One of the policies is to ensure that IP forwarding is disabled on all VMs. The only place I have this enabled is on the NVA, which I exempted from the policy. So with that exempted and no other VMs with IP forwarding enabled on the NIC, I'm still getting compliance issues. But for the compliance reason I see "NotFound".

When looking at the resource out of compliance, it does NOT have IP forwarding enabled. I've rescanned the resource groups and still get this weird non-compliance error. Not finding anything in Azure documentation on what this is all about. The error itself lists:

> **Reason for non-compliance:**
> No related resources match the effect details in the policy definition. (Error code: NotFound)

The specific policy is:

> IP Forwarding on your virtual machine should be disabled

Looking for ideas on why I'm getting a non-compliance of "NotFound" and why my exemption for the NVA isn't giving it a pass.

Thanks.

Comment: [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/how-to/determine-non-compliance)

Comment: I saw that, but the description of the  "A resource of the type defined in then.details.type and related to the resource defined in the if portion of the policy rule doesn't exist." doesn't make sense to me. The then.details.type in the policy is  "Microsoft.Security/assessments". This policy is bundled in the Azure Security Benchmark. It seems this policy just doesn't do anything useful at all. It should be "Network interfaces should disable IP forwarding" with the Deny effect..